# SSRS: UserName value in Subscriptions table, ExtensionSettings column

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

SSRS subscription to a Windows File Share.  Is there a way to query for all the "credentials used to access the file share" in plain text?  It appears that the UserName value in the ExtensionSettings column is hashed (and different for the same user for many reports).

I am trying to identify all the reports that a single account is being used to access the file shares.